# Run downloaded file from class after it's downloaded

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got a Form that i'm downloading a file from. I have a separate class (download.cs) that handles the download of the file and the progress etc. I can't work out how to run the file once it's completed. I can see the event that runs once its downloaded, but at that point I want to resume what's going on in the calling routine.

**Form1.cs**

```
  private void btnDownloadProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                tc.SelectTab("tabLog");
                Download d = new Download();
                d.DownloadFile("http://www.****.com/Downloads/***.zip", appPath + @"Files\***.zip", "Filename");
                //At this point i'd like to wait for the download to finish and then execute the download
            }
```

**Download.cs**

```
 WebClient webClient; 
        public void DownloadFile(String URL, String Path, String Name)
        {
            using (webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
                Uri Link = new System.Uri(URL);
                try
                {
                    Log.addLog("Attempting to download: " + Name);
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(Link, Path);       
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.addLog(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        { 
           Log.addLog(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
        }

        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                Log.addLog("Download has been canceled.");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.addLog("Download completed!");
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**
For clarification. Once the button is clicked, the event runs on Form1.cs which kicks off the download. This then goes in to the background using the Async stuff and free's up the UI. I can see in the log file the download happening. Once the Compelted item runs in Download.cs I can tell that the file has finished downloading. However, I can't at that point seem to work out which file has finished downloading, it just tells me a file has downloaded. How can I either pass through to Completed the filename, or hold up the event on  btnDownloadProfile_Click until the file has finished to work with it after.

Comment: You just want to open the ZIP file after downloading?
With you program or just execute the default program to open zip file?

There is solution to both: System.IO.Compression
The other is: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start

Comment: Hi, Sorry I mean I know how to extract or run the file once it's downloaded. What I don't get is how the Completed routine can get the file details etc once it's downloaded and continue the sub routine on the form1

Comment: I don't understand :c Could you edit your question and be more specific on what you want :3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, You want to download the file and then continue where you have called the download method... If this is correct, you can use TaskCompletionSource class with async/await

(BTW: You can simply use `DownloadFileTaskAsync` if *showing the download progress* is not a must )

Usage:

```
async void YourMethod()
{

    var dl = new SODownloader();
    await dl.DownloadFile(........);
    //Do whatever you want to do. Download is finsished....            
}
```

Your modified downloader class

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SO3
{
    public class SODownloader
    {
        WebClient webClient;
        TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(); //<-----

        public Task DownloadFile(String URL, String Path, String Name)
        {

            using (webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
                Uri Link = new System.Uri(URL);
                try
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Attempting to download: " + Name);
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(Link, Path);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            return tcs.Task; //<-----
        }

        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
        }

        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(new TaskCanceledException("Download has been canceled.")); //<-----
                Debug.WriteLine("Download has been canceled.");
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult("Download completed!"); //<-----
                Debug.WriteLine("Download completed!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to make sense to me - the only problem i'm getting is Error CS1061 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' on  Download d = new Download();
            await d.DownloadFile("http://www.***.com/Downloads/***.zip", appPath + @"Files\***.zip", "Profile Wizzard");

Comment: @Tom I tested it before posting, so I can't say anything more at this point.. Are you using .Net>= 4.5 ?

Comment: Aha! .net 4 - upgraded and it works now. Thanks so much, that's a really useful thing to know